# @font-face rendering issue on paragraph tag, Chrome Android 4

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, tablet

I am running into a strange issue in Chrome on a Nexus 7, Android 4 tablet.

When I try to style a `p` tag with a web font, the font will not render until it is after a certain `em`or `px` size:

The CSS:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'mija';
        src: url('/assets/fonts/mija-reg/mija-reg.eot');
        src: url('/assets/fonts/mija-reg/mija-reg.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('/assets/fonts/mija-reg/mija-reg.woff') format('woff'),
        url('/assets/fonts/mija-reg/mija-reg.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('/assets/fonts/mija-reg/mija-reg.svg#mija') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: 'mija'
    }
```

And my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this instance, anything `17px` and above will correctly render the font.

This is only happening on the `p` tag. Every other element will render the font at any size without issue.

I have tried with 3 different font families. I am not using any normalize files or any other CSS.

I attempted to create a fiddle but the web font is not pulling from Google's web service on Android Chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/yxcec/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this to be a bug in Webkit.

It appears as if this may be the relevant bug or related to the problem:

**Android Chrome font zoom breaks web fonts**

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138257

Answer (score 2):

Totally agree that this is a bug as already answered by @Yahreen.

I noticed that whilst I had this problem with a site I was working on that some pages seemed to work better than others. So I spent some time to try and work out why this was and if any sort of "workaround" could be used in the meantime.

I personally had problems getting Webfonts to render correctly on Chrome in Android - Nexus S and Nexus 7.

I've found that if you play with the width of your elements it appears to be possible to workaround the bug to some extent and still get web fonts under 18px to render correctly.

In the sample code attached it seems everything works on a max width of 88.8%. You can have a wider first DIV but then it breaks the ones underneath. Everything only seems to work at that magic percentage. It might be an ok workaround for some people. Your mileage may vary and you may need to play with the percentages - I needed to tweak the percentage up slightly in a responsive layout (gridpak) but I suspect it probably still conforms to the same sort of logic in overall percentage terms. After all the behaviour of this bug is strange but this does seem to sort of stabilise it into some usable pattern and maybe this helps you out.

Somebody else might understand a bit deeper what is at play here and maybe offer some more advice/explanation.

You can see the test here: http://richhollis.github.com/grumpy-wizard-font-test/

```
<!DOCTYPE>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Grumpy Wizards</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Finger+Paint' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <style>
      body { font-family: 'Finger Paint', cursive; }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body style="margin:0; padding:0; background-image: url('http://www.thezorklibrary.com/history/image/grumpy_wizard1a.png')">

    <div style="width: 88.8%; background: red; opacity: 0.8">
      <h1>Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</h1>
      <h2>Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</h2>
      <p>Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</p>
      <p style="font-size:18px">18px Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</p>
      <p style="font-size:17px">17px Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</p>
    </div>

    <div style="width: 88.8%; background: yellow; opacity: 0.8">
      <h1>Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</h1>
      <h2>Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</h2>
      <p>Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</p>      
      <p style="font-size:18px">18px Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</p>
      <p style="font-size:17px">17px Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</p>
    </div>

    <div style="width: 88.8%; background: purple; opacity: 0.8">
      <h1>Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</h1>
      <h2>Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</h2>
      <p>Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</p>      
      <p style="font-size:18px">18px Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</p>
      <p style="font-size:17px">17px Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</p>
    </div>    

    <div id="size"></div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script>$(function(){ 
      $("#size").text("window.innerWidth = " + window.innerWidth);
    });</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into this issue constantly. When the parent container of the offending element is sized using percentages or ems, the webfont breaks. When it's sized with pixels, the font works fine.

To figure out if this alone was the issue, I made a very basic page with three blocks, one sized using %, one sized using ems and one using pxs. The web font rendered fine in every block on the Nexus 7, which leads me to believe this alone is not the issue.

I notice that if you switch the orientation of the tablet, and then switch back, the webfonts all appear fine. What's more strange is the same webfont is displaying fine in some sections of the site and not in others.

My overall experience with webfonts on the Nexus 7 is extremely inconsistent and confusing. I don't think this is a webkit bug or an android bug as chrome on my android phone has never given me the same headache.

This is very frustrating...